# Random serialization exceptions using Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization

I'm trying to send data back and forth between only two computers using a Socket. The data is in the form of serialized Packet objects.

When testing the program on another computer on my local network, I'm getting random SerializationExceptions so that no data goes through.

The program consistently sends different data, so when it makes another pass at sending it again, it will sometimes go through and sometimes hit the same SerializationException again. If I catch the exception and leave it running, all data eventually makes it through, but it takes several tries.

The exception says: "The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are [byte data]"

Not sure exactly where my problem lies. The larger amounts of data I send (~100kb max) **always** go through. The smaller ones (50-70 bytes) have trouble. Here's everything to do with my serialization and reading/writing data.

Socket defined as such:

```
SocketMain = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

Send & Read methods. I'm aware this is probably a horrible way to do so and might end up being my issue. Suggestions?:

```
    public void SendPacket(Packet P)
    {
            using (MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream())
            {
                BinaryFormatter BF = new BinaryFormatter();
                BF.Serialize(MS, P);
                SocketMain.Send(MS.ToArray());
            }
    }

    public void ReadPacket()
    {
        byte[] BufferArray = new byte[131072];
        int BytesReceived = SocketMain.Receive(BufferArray);

        byte[] ActualData = new byte[BytesReceived];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BufferArray, 0, ActualData, 0, BytesReceived);

        using (MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream(ActualData))
        {
            BinaryFormatter BF = new BinaryFormatter();
            HandlePacket((Packet)BF.Deserialize(MS));
        }
    }
```

Example Packet object. This is one of my smaller ones. I *think* this might be the one that is causing the issue, but I don't know how I could tell.

```
[Serializable()]
public class Packet4BlockVerify : Packet, ISerializable
{
    public byte Index;
    public string MD5Hash;

    public Packet4BlockVerify(int Index, string MD5Hash): base(4)
    {
        this.Index = (byte)Index;
        this.MD5Hash = MD5Hash;
    }

    protected Packet4BlockVerify(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        this.ID = info.GetByte("ID");
        this.Index = info.GetByte("Index");
        this.MD5Hash = info.GetString("MD5Hash");
    }

    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("ID", this.ID);
        info.AddValue("Index", this.Index);
        info.AddValue("MD5Hash", this.MD5Hash);
    }
}
```

Does anyone see anything wrong?

Comment: Where is your socket.send/receive lines in your thread?I deal with send/receive data in local network by adding a header and footer to packet then in receiver part reading net till find header.

Comment: I'm only using a local computer for testing. The program is intended to be used over the internet.

Packet sending and receiving has ended up mostly on the same thread, where when a packet is received it is immediately responded to by sending another appropriate packet.

Comment: I don't see any special note to your released code but, thought that your logic isn't tricky enough.There are some standard Net programming  examples might help you.for your question a complete source code is required to reproduce it's bug.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not reading  all the bytes you sent. Your receive call:

```
int BytesReceived = SocketMain.Receive(BufferArray);
```

returns any number of bytes. You will need to pre-pend the bytes you send with the size of the remaining bytes, read that then continue reading till you have all your bytes before trying to deserialize.

TCP sends a continuous byte stream so your receive call reads arbitrary sized chunks. One of the overloads you can specify the number of bytes you want to receive so after reading the number bytes you are expecting you could use that. e.g.

```
// Warning untested! (but you get the idea)

// when sending
var payload = MS.ToArray();
var payloadSize = payload.Length;
mySocket.Send(BitConverter.GetBytes(payloadSize));
mySocket.Send(payload);

// when recieving
mySocket.Recieve(myBuffer, sizeof(int), SocketFlags.None);
var payloadSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(myBuffer, 0);
mySocket.Recieve(myBuffer, payloadSize, SocketFlags.None);
// now myBuffer from index 0 - payloadSize contains the payload you sent
```

Comment: It looks as if you're correct. I used the console to log how much was sent & received and I'm not getting the whole thing. I'm not exactly sure how I would go about doing what you said, though. Could you post an example?

Comment: Makes sense. Still getting some odd (different) errors with serialization but it does work a lot better now.

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: Stopped working after a few more changes. I'm getting a SerializationException: "Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader." after sending a few packets. Now I'm getting the same length of data that I sent, but it's not the same actual data. MD5 hashes are different.

Comment: when deserializing remember only to use the x number of bytes in your buffer, not your entire buffer, could that be it?

Comment: I think it's something unrelated to actually sending and reading the packets since a few do make it through. Might be something worthy of another question. I'm deserializing this byte array after reading into buffer: "byte[] Payload = BufferArray.Take(PayloadSize).ToArray();"